# How to get an array from Postgresql database using Golang's GORM?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to get multiple values from Postgresql database using Golang's jinzhu GORM.
My query can return either none, one or multiple values. I want them saved into an array
Here is code snippet:

```
    var zones []string 
    d := db //database

    d.Raw(`SELECT
           DISTINCT reg.name
           FROM
           regions reg
           LEFT JOIN
           ad_regions adreg ON adreg.region_id = reg.id
           WHERE adreg.id = ?`, ID).Scan(&zones)
```

I also tried doing this

```
var zones []string
rows, _ := d2.Raw(`SELECT
                    DISTINCT reg.name
                    FROM
                    regions reg
                    LEFT JOIN
                    ad_regions adreg ON adreg.region_id = reg.id
                    WHERE adreg.id = ?`, ad.ID).Rows()
defer rows.Close()
for rows.Next() {
                var zone string
                rows.Scan(&zone)
                zones = append(zones, zone)
                }
```

I am getting nothing from query.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Check the errors returned by Rows() and Scan().

Comment: Tried to make PG array? like `array_agg(...) from ...`?

Comment: Try call `Debug()` before `Raw()` for show detailed respond information

Comment: Thank you all for your help :)

I tried checking the Rows error as Cerise Limon suggested, and it turned out to be a misspelling error for one of my columns in database. A silly mistake, sorry for bothering the StackO community :(
Thanks for help!

P.S. if anyone comes to this problem, just take an advice from Cerise and use https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go with "log.Fatal" function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a misspelled error in my database query. Wrong column name.
Cerise Limon's advice helped.
If anyone comes to this problem, just check [Go's Error Handling](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) and use log.Fatal